# Sound range and depth it travells whe it hits sound

Tags: electromagnetism, spectroscopy, absorption

I know most people hear from 20hz to 20000hz and about the absorption spectrum of water [absorption spectrum of water link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electromagnetic_absorption_by_water) but how deep does sound travel when it hits the skin and which range of frequencies travel the farthest when it hits skin.  Basically what is the absorption spectrum of skin in respect to sound. Does a chart exist that has a large range from sound to light wavelengths?  Can this be calculated?

Thanks

I was interested when I read this article
[Music for the skin: a Nova program made by PBS link](http://www.pbs.org/wgbh/nova/next/body/haptic-hearing/)

Answer (score 0):

Generally the higher the frequency the more will be absorbed in a given medium. 20Hz will go right through you, and you will feel it. However, if you are talking about [ultrasonic imaging](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Medical_ultrasound) there is a tradeoff between resolution and wavelength (frequency). Shorter wavelengths (higher frequencies) will give you a better image but be absorbed more strongly.

As for [attenuation in the body, this might be of use](http://usra.ca/tissue.php)